# NodeJs Canvas does not appear

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-canvas

I am installing node js canvas API using the following code:

```
npm install canvas --save
```

I have written code for displaying a canvas, but it doesn't show anything. The code doesn't show errors on executing:

```
const { createCanvas } = require('canvas')
const width = 1200
const height = 600

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

context.fillStyle = '#fff'
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
```

Comment: Hi, there is more than what you wrote in the sample code from the `npm` page of the package you are using. And in the example code, I see that it saves the process to a jpg file. https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Comment: ```
loadImage('examples/images/lime-cat.jpg').then((image) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70);
 
  console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />')
})
```

Comment: I want to know is it need an HTML file to show that images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package provides us a Node.js based implementation of the **Canvas API** that we know and love in the browser.

Except instead of getting a **Canvas** instance from a `<canvas>` HTML element, We load the library, get the function `createCanvas` out of it.

Example:

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.rotate(0.1)
ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)
 
// Draw line under text
var text = ctx.measureText('Awesome!')
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
ctx.stroke()
 
// Draw cat with lime helmet
loadImage('./imgs.jpg').then((image) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)
 
  console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />')
})
```

Comment: yea thank you when I run this nothin happens in the terminal I want to appear output window.it doesn't appear at all

Comment: I have updated my answer! Check now you will get `base64` of png.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Windows, you need to follow the installation steps on their GitHub:
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Windows

Building the node-canvas module requires:

1. A global installation of node-gyp.
2. GTK 2
3. For optional JPEG support (node-canvas 2.0 and later): libjpeg-turbo

If u are using any other OS, u can find instructions for your OS in their README, in Compiling section: 
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Answer (score 0):

Im replying to this thread that is 2 years old but I know the answer

I believe you want a PNG output (a simple photo). You made properly the image but you forgot to export it. Here is how to:

```
const { createCanvas } = require('canvas')
const width = 1200
const height = 600

//choose here were your file must be saved
let imagepath = "images/photo.png"

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

context.fillStyle = '#fff'
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

//here is the new part that saves the image to a path
const out = fs.createWriteStream(imagepath),
stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
stream.pipe(out);
```

This simple script will save under **images/photo.png** your desired photo.